# Is there a way to determine whether upgrading to a newer version of Android OS will slow down my device?

Tags: android-versions

Is there some way to test whether *my device is ready for version xyz* of Android (i.e., how much it will slow down the device?

Or some sort of table of how much slower each version of Android has become.

Comment: Installing the new version would be a way to test. Alternatively, you have to rely on hearing from other people who've done that, but to get that kind of information, you need to tell us what phone you have and what version you're thinking of upgrading to.

Comment: In my limited experience, I've not been able to uninstall OS upgrades to my android phone.

Answer (score 0):

Well, no there is no any test which could help you in determining, and yes one more thing OS upgrades make your device faster rather than slower. So I am sorry but I don't think that there is any use  of asking such question. Flashing ROM other than the stock ROM can results in decreasing speed or other similar problems but I don't think that downloading and installing the OS upgrades received directly from the vendor will slow your device down, because before feeding those ROM over the air they perform a number of test to give your flawless experience.

Answer (score -1):

There is no "test" to my knowledge like there was for windows. However, to ensure the best results from an upgrade I recommend factory resetting your phone after you back up your information. This will ensure no third party app incompatibilities with the updated software.